# How to add hidden field to the column on which highchart.js for table is applied

Tags: highcharts

How can i add hidden field in the column on which the highchart for table is applied?

Example:

```
column A , Column B , Column C
ABC , 123 with hidden input field, 345 with hidden input field
```

As soon as I add a hidden field to these column, script throws an error with code `14`

Comment: Could you create jsFiddle demo with that issue?

Comment: I am thinking to skip some columns in between two column on which highcharts for table js is applied...is there any why to do this??

Comment: nevermind I edited your js and made it to skip columns inbetween... :) anyways thanx... :)